# Azure API gateway vs nginx

Tags: nginx, azure-api-management, api-gateway

I am evaluating wep api gateway for my new projects. I used azure api gateway in the past. Reading about nginx as it is new and adopted by many. Can someone help me point out with some facts, pros, cons? Bug matrix will be a best help for me

Answer (score 2):

Azure API Management is a mature and widely-used product, with many customers being very respected enterprises. Take a look at some [public case studies](http://aka.ms/apimcustomers).

It offers a very wide range of features, which are typical of an API management platform, and it is still being very actively developed. However, one of its biggest strengths lies in integration with Microsoft Azure services and features - multiregional deployments, virtual networks, monitoring and alerting solutions, native support for Service Fabric, Azure Function Apps and Azure Logic Apps, Azure Active Directory and others.

If you are considering hosting your new projects with Microsoft Azure, Azure API Management is a no-brainier.

The product is also one of the main reasons why [Gartner named Microsoft a leader in the enterprise integration space](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/gartner-recognizes-microsoft-as-a-leader-in-enterprise-integration/).

*Disclaimer: Although all of the above is best to my knowledge, I am affiliated with Azure API Management.*

Answer (score 0):

Although I have just started looking into this myself, here's what I can already conclude.

- Looking at [www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/](https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/), Nginx requires a lot of manual configuration washed over many text files. That doesn't look flexible or effective, but I may have gotten a wrong impression.
- Judging by how you're supposed to define your API keys using the `map` directive, Nginx API Gateway also looks like a new idea stretched on top of the existing product, while Azure API was designed for that exact purpose from the ground up.
- Azure APIs, when published, [come with auto-generated documentation and an interactive console](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7CJphbEmk4) that are in sync with all your updates.
- With Azure API, you're putting all your eggs into one basket and completely depending on it's pricing and availability. At any moment Microsoft can increase their prices, or discontinue the product, and you cannot migrate elsewhere, at least not easily/quickly. At the same time, you can do your Nginx work once and run it on pretty much any server, starting with a low-end VPS or a Raspberry PI, if you'd like. It's pretty much yours.